# EKS NodePort service not accessible from outside cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a two-node EKS cluster set up in AWS.

On that cluster, I have a `deployment` with two replicas of a simple web application.

I have also created a `service` to expose this deployment, using the `kubectl expose deployment app --type=NodePort` command. Here's the output for the service:

```
Selector:                 app=app,environment=production
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       172.20.162.107
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30818/TCP
Endpoints:                10.5.2.128:80,10.5.2.86:80
```

**The pods and the service are in the `production` namespace.**

Everything appears to be working correctly - the pods are healthy, the logs are exactly as I'd expect to see, etc.

If I SSH to one of the EKS nodes and `curl localhost:30818` (the NodePort defined on the service), I get a basic HTTP web page in response - as expected.

The output of `lsof -i TCP:30818` shows that the server is listening on this port:

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
kube-prox 23746 root   13u  IPv6 119697770      0t0  TCP *:30818 (LISTEN)
```

However, if I try to do this using the EKS instances' public IP addresses, it fails.

I know my security groups are set up correctly because by adding `iptables -A FORWARD -s <<myIP>> -j LOG` then running `tail -f /var/log/messages`, I can see traffic from my IP addresses being forwarded by iptables.

In summary:

- The traffic is getting to the server (iptables logs)
- The server is listening on the port (lsof output)
- I can see the pod logs
- I can curl `localhost` on the service NodePort and get the expected response
- From within a pod I can access the DNS hostname of the service etc.
- ... **but I can't access this port using the server's public IP**

What am I missing?

Comment: check kube proxy logs on that node

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu looks fine - `{"log":"I0820 10:22:26.902018       1 proxier.go:1464] Opened local port \"nodePort for production/app:\" (:30818/tcp)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-08-20T10:22:26.902128791Z"}`